# undefined offset: 1 in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I got problem undefined offset. Here is my controller:

```
    if($request->submit == "online")
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['speciality'])){
         $users = User::where('speciality','=',$_POST['speciality'])->orWhere('speciality1','=',$_POST['speciality'])
         ->orWhere('speciality2','=',$_POST['speciality'])->get();
         return view('result',compact('users')); 
         }
   }
```

I am using laravel 6.
And here is my blade:

```
@foreach($users)
hello {{$user['full_name']}} 
@endforeach
```

I need help for this please. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using orWhere on a collection (i.e. after calling ->get()). You can't do that. You need to use it on models (well, query builder).

So your code should look something like:

```
     if($request->submit == "online")
     {
        if(!empty($_POST['speciality'])){
         $onlineUsers = User:: where('online_position','=',1);
         $users = $onlineUsers>where('speciality','=',$_POST['speciality'])
         ->orWhere('speciality1','=',$_POST['speciality'])
         ->orWhere('speciality2','=',$_POST['speciality'])->get();
         return view('result',compact('users')); 
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually cannot use orWhere in this case because you have alreardy executed the query by calling the get() method, after that the result will be a collection not a query builder.

The solution should just be to remove the first get method call.